# How do I mount this non-standard wall plate to a completed drywall wall?

Tags: electrical, drywall, switch

I have this
[image]

But it only has what you see in that pic. I was told I needed the box thing to go behind it to mount it to in the wall. There is no hole in the wall right now, so how do I get this to fit and stay securely? Also, it is standard width, but not as tall as a regular lightswitch faceplate.

[Here's the exact one I bought, actually](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005DC49PW). 
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use a low-voltage retrofit mounting bracket, which is the same size and has the same screw dimensions as a standard outlet box, but without the "box" part.

[image: Retrofit bracket PID 7013 on www.monoprice.com]

Because it's low-voltage, you don't need the mechanical protection of the box like you do for high-voltage. It also gives you a lot more room to work with, which is very nice for bulky connectors like the HDMI and VGA ones you have.

After you cut the appropriate sized hole in the wall, you mount the bracket and it clamps down onto the drywall. Then you can run the wires into it and attach the faceplate, just like you would with any box mounted in the wall.

Here's what it looks like in the wall (this one is orange, but otherwise the same thing):

[image: retrofit box in wall]

---

Note, there are also low-voltage mounting plates for new construction, which are basically the same thing but go up before drywall and attach directly to a stud.

[image: New construction low-voltage mounting bracket]

Comment: I edited in pics from amazon of the purchased product - it looks to have standard placed mounting holes.